# Setting up network storage

Tags: networking, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata, nas

My girlfriend and I have MacBook Pros which we recently upgraded to SSD's. As a result of that, we have two spare 2.5 SATA HDDs that have no use except as network drives. I can definitely buy cheap USB enclosures and use them as external hard drives, but that still doesn't seem ideal to me. What I'd like doing is using these disks as network storage so that we can :

1. Store shared pictures/movies on the disks.
2. Connect the shared disks to our smart TV for instant hassle free access (over the network).

What would be the best way to go about this? I've been looking on the web for Ethernet enabled 2.5" HDD enclosures but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NAS is more than a disk, an enclosure, and an ethernet port: it includes the software to handle all of this (for instance, the handling of permissions, access lists, passwords, and so on) and the hardware that goes with that software.

So what you need to buy is a **diskless NAS**; you will find many just about anywhere, online or in a store. Just make sure the model you chose can host two, 2.5in disks: some only host a single disk, and some only 3.5in disks. But that's all.

Comment: Ok, I live in Europe and I can buy on Amazon.de; and I cannot seem to find any of them. Can you tell me which search terms to use?

Comment: @Ashesh Try this: http://www.amazon.de/Synology-DiskStation-Diskless-Attached-DS411slim/dp/B004L87XAC/ref=pd_sim_sbs_e_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=02K414G7KS42HGM5ZZA5